# Export CSV file (without changing the page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Export", {:action => :export}, :method => :post%>
```

record_controller.rb

```
 def export
   csv_file = CSV.generate({}) do |csv|
   csv << @data_filtered.first.keys
   @data_filtered.each do |hash|
     csv << hash.values
   end
 end
 send_data csv_file, :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present', :disposition => "attachment; filename=tester1.csv"
end
```

I am wondering how to do this because @data_filtered is an instance variable sent to show.view but it no longer exists when I click export (this is the data i want to export to a .csv).  Is there a way to pass this data through link_to?  I am also anticipating the issue that this is going to change the view which I dont want to do.

Comment: You need to find back the entity you want to export. If in your show action you have something like `@record = Record.where(id: params[:id]).first`, then you have to set it in the export action too. You can use the url-helper `record_export_path(id: @record.id)` (depending on your routes) for the link_to in order to pass data through `link_to` via GET method.

Comment: In my show method a lot of logic is done to manipulate the entity that I would prefer not to do again

Comment: It is 2 distincts actions, responding to 2 distincts requests path, which means you would need to redo your "lot of logic" before exporting to CSV for each action.

Comment: can't you use a GET request instead of POST, and just target it to a new window/tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two basic approaches:

- In your 'show' method, save what's in `@data-filtered` to your model.  Then you can find it again in the 'export' method.
- Or, you have to send it all down to the client, and the client will have to send it all back.